# How to use json data in MVC view .cshtml

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

I hope someone can help me:
My challenge is, that I have a web service returning a json.

The format is

```
{"stations":[{"name":"aname","free":false},{"name":"anothername","free":true}]}
```

so I have one object which is an array that hold `n` objects with `n` attributes....
Now for each object in that array of the stations object I would like to render the attributes, like

```
<p>stations[0].name</p>
```

I need to use this in mvc.
So I created a model

```
public station(){}
public string name {get; set;}
public boolean free {get; set;}
```

in my contorller I use a WebClient and now I need to handle the response.
I was thinking of IEnumerable but I don't know how to put this in the view?!

my goal is to understand how i can do something like

```
public Actionresult Stations(){
var stations = JObject.Load(reponse);
return View(Stations);
}
```

but I have no idea how to the handle each object of the array and get their values in the `Stations.cshtml` view using for each or similar....

Any idea?

Comment: is that web service deployed in the same domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, this is my way.

#### Model

Create a class in which your JSON will be deserialized to:

```
public class RootJson
{
    public IEnumerable<station> Stations { get; set; }
}
```

The `RootJson` class has a property which will contain a list of `station`'s instances (your class):

```
public class station
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool free { get; set; }
}
```

---

#### Controller

Then, deserialize your JSON using:

```
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(json);
```

And pass the stations to the view:

```
return View(deserialized.Stations);
```

---

#### View

In your view you have to specify the type of the data passed, in this case `IEnumerable<station>`. So, at the top of your `Stations.cshtml` add:

```
@model IEnumerable<station>
```

You can use a `foreach` to iterate over the model:

```
@foreach(var station in Model)
{
    <p>@station.name</p>
}
```

---

### Edit: Full code for clarification

#### Model

*RootJson.cs*

```
public class RootJson
{
    public IEnumerable<station> Stations { get; set; }
}
```

*station.cs*

```
public class station
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public bool free { get; set; }
}
```

#### Controller

Inside *YourController.cs*

```
public ActionResult Stations() {
    string json = YourMethodToGetJsonAsString();
    var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(json);
    return View(deserialized.Stations);
}
```

#### View

*Stations.cshtml*

```
@model IEnumerable<station>

@foreach(var station in Model)
{
    <p>@station.name</p>
}
```

Comment: So I actually make 2 models, one for the jsonand one for the stations in the json? I wil try that tomorrow!! Thx!!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, @omaxel!.

Comment: Unfortunately i still get the problem not beeing able to use IEnumerable in my view. IDE tells me, that <station> (as type or namespace) can not be found when using 
    '@model IEnumerable<station>
in the controller it knows station as  IEnumerable<station> of RootJson.Stations, but not in the view.....

Comment: Yes and no. Theoretically you have a model which is wrapped in class because of your JSON.

Comment: When using a model in a view you should use the full namespace too. So, make sure your `station` is accesible from the view. For example, if your namespace in which the class is declared is `WebApplication1.Models`, then in your view you have to use `IEnumerable<WebApplication1.Models.station`. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks again @omaxel, but even if i use the full path (and the attributes are available when i press . , like .id is shown) I will receive error: NullReferenceException 
I can't access the model in the view...

Comment: Ok @David don't worry. Try to debug it. Can you check that `deserialized` is not null? Also, are you shure the input JSON string is as you indicated in the question? Try with static JSON as input (for example `var json = @"{ ""stations"":[{""name"":""aname"",""free"":false},{""name"":""anothername"",""free"":true}]}"`)

Comment: Yes @omaxel, I really appreciate your input and it sounds logical so I don't  nkow whats goin on. I tried toi debug as follows: I tried with the json as string created in the controller. This does work. So I thought it was the prox, so I added all necessary proxy info, still doesn't work. So i tried the not serialized response (client downloadfstring) and used Viewbag to show it in the view, and that shows the whole data. but the deserialization does not work.... ;-(

Comment: I'm a little confused about your test. Why use Viewbag if passing the model works? However, the problem seems to be at request level and not at parsing level for which the question is for. Please search solution for your other problem or make another question.

Comment: Thanks again @omaxel. I was using ViewBag to check the response iin the view via ViewBag.Message. I does work if my response is unparsed/ unconverted, I get the ull response as string passed to the view. but converting and reading IEnumerable does not work....

Comment: Sorry but what do you mean with "I get the ull response as string passed to the view"? By the way, I posted the full code. Please test it in two steps:

1) Replace `YourMethodToGetJsonAsString()` with a static string like the one in my comment below. If it works proceed to step 2.
2) Replace `YourMethodToGetJsonAsString()` with your method which makes the real request and return the json as string. If it doesn't work, the problem is the new introduced function.

Comment: I tried 1) a while ago and that works, but with escaped quotes only.... (\"name instead of "name, but i am getting "name...)  @omaxel. but 2) doesn't . I think the deserialization doesnt' work. json.encode doesn't work either. I am lost and I think I have to give up on this one....

Comment: Hi again.
Many thanks to all of you! this place is great!
@omaxel : You were right, basically, but I needed to use a single instance!

So it's not

var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(json);

but

RootJson deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(json);


With this it does work!

Comment: The two version with `var` and `RootJson` are basically the same. When you use `var` the compiler autodetects the return type of `DeserializeObject<RootJson>` which is clearly `RootJson`. BTW, Glad to help you :-). If I solved your problem, please make this answer as accepted.

Comment: strange, but yes! Very good job (and you don't get evewn paid!)) I marked this as correct answer.
However: If I use var it does not work!

Answer (score 0):

One of simplest way is to use ViewBag like this:

```
public ActionResult Stations()
{
    string jsonString = "{ \"stations\":[{\"name\":\"aname\",\"free\":false},{\"name\":\"anothername\",\"free\":true}]}";
    ViewBag.stations = ((dynamic)Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString)).stations;
    return View();
}
```

and inside cshtml for ex.

```
<p>@ViewBag.stations[0].name</p>
```

Comment: To much hard coding.

Comment: I don't know ViewBag, so I will look into it, but: I would replace the string here with response, right?

Comment: It depends on what your `response` is. If it is a string you may simple use it instead of `jsonString`. If it is something else you need to convert it to object model.

Answer (score 0):

**Model**

```
public class Stations
{
    public List<Station> Station { get; set; }
}
public class Station
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool Free { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
// Deserialising JSON
var station = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Stations>(response);
// Pass result to view
return View(station.Station);
```

**View**

At the top of your `Stations.cshtml` add:

```
@model IEnumerable<Station>
```

You can use a `foreach` to iterate over the model:

```
@foreach(var station in Model)
{
    <p>@station.Name</p>
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for answering! I guess <Users> is a typo? I will try tomorrow and let you know!

Comment: Yeah, it is a typo. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Model data convert to Json format in controller

   ```
   JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
   result.Data = model;
   result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
   return result;
   ```
2. In the view get Json data in TextBox

   ```
   $.ajax(
               {
                   type: 'POST',
                   url: "/Student/GetStudent",
                   data: { ID: ID },               
                   dataType: "json",
                   success: function (result) {
                       $("#StudentName").val(result.StudentName);
                       $("#Gender").val(result.Gender);
                       $("#Email").val(result.Email);    
               }    
    })
   ```